# How to load a ruby file (main.rb) in cronjob using whenever gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron

I have just installed whenever gem in my rails3 application. It is fantastic to use and i can 
send emails on regular time. But unable to load any ruby file with command in cronjob. Here is code i have done so far:

In my schedule.rb:

```
set :environment, :development


every 1.days, :at => '6pm' do
 runner "User.hello_user", :output => 'log/cron.log'
end

every 2.minutes do
  command "load(File.read('app/models/summary_created.rb'))", :output => 'log/cron.log'
end
```

and here is my cronjob list:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: myapp
0 18 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/ruby-projects/myapp && script/rails runner -e development '\''User.hello_user'\'' >> log/cron.log 2>&1'

0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'load(File.read('\''app/models/summary_created.rb'\'')) >> log/cron.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: myapp
```

in above file my first task works well but it is not running second task. Can i get the list of command it is supporting or any other way to run that file. For now i run it manually from rails console:

```
 irb(main):030:0> load "summary_created.rb"
```

Please help me to find out what i am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Use `webmin setup` for setting your cron jobs. It's very simple and easy to use. I have implemented it into all of my projects.

Comment: Hi @Sumit Munot can you please give some more details about webmin setup, how it works is it suitable for cronjob?